# How to bind a function/constant to a variable, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, pdo

I'm trying to make a nice little function to do my `PDO` binding for me:

```
function autoBind($result, $values)
{
$i = 1 ;
foreach($values as $currentValue) {
    if(is_numeric($currentValue))
    {
        $bindType = PDO::PARAM_INT ;
    }
    elseif(is_string($currentValue) || is_float($currentValue))
    {
        $bindType = PDO::PARAM_STR ;
    }
    else
    {
        return false ; // Error
    }
    $result->bindParam($i, $currentValue, $bindType) ;
    $i++ ;
}
$result->execute() ;
}
```

But it's not working. If I echo `$bindType`, it comes out as "1" and then "2".

What do I need to do to make it give me what I want?

---

Thanks for your replies,

Is this as safe as manually binding?

In what situation would you manually bind?

Comment: If you are using PDO, you don't need to do this. Just pass an array to `execute()`. It's MySQLi where you have to do all the above messing about.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know about that. Is that just as safe as doing the above? I want to make my transactions etc as safe as I can.

Comment: Bear in mind that `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PARAM_STR` are constants defined somewhere in PDO - they do actually have the values of 1 and 2.

Comment: @imperium2335 It is no more or less safe that using `bindParam()`. Once you start using prepared statements, it's no longer an issue. As long as you don't start leaking user input into the statement string before passing it to `prepare()`, of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for this function, as [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) already supports passing in an array of parameters.  Simply do:

```
$result->execute( $values );
```

Comment: if you do this and have a numeric value like for example "ID" the bind result will be a string, pdo might generate something like "...WHERE id = '50' which will result in error and not WHERE id = 50 so sometimes you need to define the PDO::PARAM_INT if you need numbers and use bindParam/bindValue

Comment: @qxxx MySQL is loosely typed and will perform type coercion where necessary (at least in the respect of string vs. int). It will still work with `PARAM_STR`, it just gives the DB engine a *little* more work to do when executing the query (although not enough more to make a meaningful difference)

Comment: Tried it out, I get the same result returned with no problems.